# POST request form data without reloading page Flask / fetch

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I know there are other similar questions but after reading all of them, I can't figure out how to make it.
I have multiple form in a page and I want to post data from each form without reloading the page.
This is the example of one of the forms. I have 5.
I get the inputs from the user like this:

```
<form method="POST" class="formGroupA">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4 class="mt-4">GRUPO A</h4>
                <table style="width: 90%" class="table table-striped table-sm m-auto">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Loop through the database entries to display them in this table -->

                        {% for match in groupA %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ match['HomeTeam'] }}</td>
                            <td><input autocomplete="off" class="pruebaInput" name="groupAHome{{ loop.index0 }}"></td>
                            <td>{{ match['AwayTeam'] }}</td>
                            <td><input autocomplete="off" class="pruebaInput" name="groupAAway{{ loop.index0 }}"></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-warning my-3" style="width:20%" type="submit">Apostar</button>
            </form>
```

I read the flask documentation that says to use **fetch()** but I am a confused about it.

> To send form data, pass a populated FormData object. This uses the same format as an HTML form, and would be accessed with request.form in a Flask view.
> **Example:**

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append("name": "Flask Room")
data.append("description": "Talk about Flask here.")
fetch(room_url, {
    "method": "POST",
    "body": data,
}).then(...)
```

So, I understand that I have to create an object FormData,d and append the inputs from the form to it.  What should I do to populate the data variable with the inputs of the user? A loop with the names of every input? And then in my app.py,do I get it with a request? like, for example: request.get(data).

I don't know if I am making any sense, this is so new to me I don't know how to ask it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you have a form like this where the form fields are given a name attribute.

```
<form name="my-form">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now you can use JavaScript to query the entire form and add a listener to it that reacts to "submit" type events.
To suppress the default behavior of the form, i.e. direct submission, you call `event.preventDefault()`, since you want to submit the form yourself. You can then pass the entire form that fired the event to the newly created FomData object. This sets the data from the form fields together with their name attributes. With the help of the fetch call you can now send all the data to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(url) {
    const form = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form"]');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        fetch(url, {
            'method': 'POST', 
            'body': formData
        }).then(resp => {
            // handle response here
        });
    });
})({{ url_for('.index') | tojson }});
</script>
```

The server-side query of the form data is done, as usual, via `request.form`. The `.get(...)` function is used to get the values of the form fields by their names.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        print(name)
        return '', 200
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Since you left open in your question what you want to return as the server's response, an empty response is returned in the example.

Comment: thank you Detlef! I understand it better now. I will continue studying.